# Read image in tensorflow with indexed color value for semantic segmentation task

Tags: python, tensorflow, semantic-segmentation

I'm creating FCN for semantic segmentation.
I'm having a difficult time with converting the labeled png image to indexed color value on PascalVOC dataset.
I want the value to be range between 0 and 20. As I can achieve such operation with PIL in the following code

```
with Image.open(image_path) as img:
    label = np.array(img)
```

it outputs what I want. But for tensorflow implementation, I want it to be same value with code like the following

```
file = tf.read_file(image_path)
label = tf.image.decode_png(file, channels=0)
```

But the tensorflow implementation results the value from 0 to 255.
Is there any way that I can achieve the PIL implementation in tensorflow as well?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SegmentationClass` file has color map component in it and so when using `tf.decode_png()` you need to specify as :

```
label = tf.image.decode_png(file, channels=3)
```

Now you have got the `RGB` values you can use [create_pascal_label_colormap()](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/utils/get_dataset_colormap.py) function to convert to class Id's.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the VOC 2012 file paths in a dataset of pairs `(image_path: tf.string, image_label_path: tf.string)`.

First, define the colors of each class:

```py
_COLORS = tf.constant([
  [0, 0, 0], [128, 0, 0], [0, 128, 0], [128, 128, 0], [0, 0, 128],
  [128, 0, 128], [0, 128, 128], [128, 128, 128], [64, 0, 0], [192, 0, 0],
  [64, 128, 0], [192, 128, 0], [64, 0, 128], [192, 0, 128], [64, 128, 128],
  [192, 128, 128], [0, 64, 0], [128, 64, 0], [0, 192, 0], [128, 192, 0],
  [0, 64, 128]
], dtype=tf.int32)
```

And the loading function:

```py
def load_images(image_path, label_path):
  image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
  image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)

  image_label = tf.io.read_file(label_path)
  image_label = tf.io.decode_png(image_label, channels=3)
  image_label = rgb_to_label(image_label)

  return image, image_label
```

```py
def rgb_to_label(segm):
  segm = tf.cast(segm[..., tf.newaxis], _COLORS.dtype)
  return tf.argmax(tf.reduce_all(segm == tf.transpose(_COLORS), axis=-2), axis=-1)
```

And just apply the function:

```py
ds = ds.map(load_images, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

---

Explanation:

`segm[..., tf.newaxis].shape == (H, W, 3, 1)`, while
`transpose(colors).shape == (3, 21)`.

Comparing both with `==` broadcasts into a tensor of shape `(H, W, 3, 21)`.
If the pixel `(h,w)` of a segmentation mask image matches the color of a certain class `c`, then all three pixel intensities in the 3rd axis will match. Hence `tf.reduce_all(...)` will reduce to a `(H, W, 21)` one-hot encoded tensor, containing `true` at the corresponding label index and `false` everywhere else.

Lastly, `tf.argmax(..., axis=-1)` finds the index itself for each pixel (resulting in a `(H, W)` image).

It's worth mentioning that argmax will default to 0 if all of them are false. So a pixel containing an unknown color (that's not present in the map `_COLORS`) will be assigned to the label 0 (the background).